# How to insert dynamic code snippets in website?

Tags: code-snippets

I have to make an **interactive** web page where students can learn by reading and running the code on the same page.

For e.g, if I am teaching "Hello world in PHP", instead of writing static code like: `echo 'Hello world';`, students should be able to run the code and see the result below the code instantly.

Is there a program which does so? The program must support html, css, javascript and php code snippets which can be run instantly on the web page with live results.

Basically, the program must be like a **jupyter notebook** for html, css, javascript and php.

I would prefer if the program supports markdown writing.

Answer (score 0):

You can have them use a real-time code emulator such as http://www.writephponline.com where they can edit the code in real time, add comments and print if needed;

Comment: But I want the code and output to be displayed on  my webpage

Comment: You can either use an iFrame or design your page with a form and use JQuery to send form values for each lesson template to a script that returns the code back to the page and possibly even include your own comments, validations, tips and ideas; those are two ways I think you can accomplish what you need.

Comment: What I mean is add that page in an iFrame eg: <iFrame src=“http://www.writephponline.com”></iFrame> which will open the page within yours; personally I’d slap 2 textarea fields and use JQuery to build a small app that takes your students input and posts it to a code validation script and returns back the results, like building your own little console; but iFrame is the quickest way to include a third party page within your page (providing the page isn’t CORS restricted); it’s worth a try if you need to get it up quick.